Fixation index calculation from the vcf files
I used the Python script FSTest (https://github.com/similab/FSTest) for the calculation of the fixation index from the extracted SNPs. I used the following command:
python FSTest1.3.py --pop1 snps_chr1.vcf --pop2 snps_chr2.vcf --m 3 --zt 1 --o chr1_chr2_fst

I received the following error: Could you please help me to solve the error?
 **************************************************************
*                 FSTest software v 1.3                      *
*       Seyed Milad Vahedi, Siavash Salek Ardestani          *
*         smvahedi@dal.ca, siasia6650@gmail.com              *
**************************************************************

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/Desktop/fst/FSTest1.3.py", line 45, in <module>
        ac1.columns=["np1","nq1"]
        ^^^^^^^^^^^

  

    File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6313, in __setattr__
        return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 814, in _set_axis
    self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 238, in set_axis
    self._validate_set_axis(axis, new_labels)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/base.py", line 98, in _validate_set_axis
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements


Reviewing the source code, I observe the following at and before line 45 where your error occurs:
pop1 = allel.read_vcf(args.pop1)
pop2 = allel.read_vcf(args.pop2)

gt1 = allel.GenotypeArray(pop1['calldata/GT'])
gt2 = allel.GenotypeArray(pop2['calldata/GT'])

ac1 = gt1.count_alleles()
ac1 = pd.DataFrame(ac1)
ac1.columns=["np1","nq1"]

Based on a naive reading, the issue seems to be that the allele counts indicate more than 2 alleles based on its dependency on scikit-allel's GenotypeArray. I believe that this means that your VCF is treating your data as triploid (?), but the FSTest1.py script strictly assumes diploidy. It would be nice if it could make that explicit.
But I am not absolutely sure as I am not an expert on these packages. I invite someone with more understanding to comment.
Can you show a snippet of your VCF or comment on the ploidy issue? What's the form of your data?

SNP data in the VCF file is diploid

@DJI can you show a sample of your VCF files?
